# There are child potentials, yet Trinity was told she would fall for the One?

Tags: the-matrix

Sorry if this question is worded wrong, feel free to edit. My question is, the potentials in the Oracles home I assume are potential **Ones**? 
So the *love* that Trinity was supposed to develop for a One wouldn't necessarily have had to been for an adult. From a perspective of, Morpheus and his crew knew that children were also being selected as potentials.

Obviously an adult makes more sense but I guess did anyone else consider the love to be more than just a romantic love.

Comment: Is the fundamental question here whether the children are potential '''Ones''' and whether they might transition to being the '''One''' while still a child? Or are you just pointing out the squick?

Comment: *"You've got the gift..."* - The implication is that the children have already been assessed and judged to ***not*** be The One.

Comment: I think the questiton is whether Trinity's prophecy could have become true by her feeling maternal love for one of the potential children. It raises another question, though: If not – if the love in the prophecy was meant to be romantic love – couldn't that be used to use the process of elimination and conclude that none of the children were The One earlier?

Comment: How old is Trinity and how old are the children? As I recall (and I watched the Matrix many times, although not lately), there was no time-frame given for when Trinity would fall in "love" with the One. So, it might not necessarily need to be maternal love.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The wording of the prophecy makes it pretty clear that the love Trinity was meant to feel for The One is a romantic one.

> "Neo, I'm not afraid anymore. **The Oracle told me that I would fall in love and that that man... the man that I loved would be The One**. So you see, you can't be dead. You can't be... because I love you. You hear me? I love you."

<sup><sup>Trinity, *The Matrix* (1999)</sup></sup>

Being **in love** with someone is very different to **loving** someone, in that it refers to romantic love over other forms of love.

As such, unless Trinity was destined to fall in love with a child (a topic I'm sure that no one wants to deal with), we know that The One was destined to be an adult.

Comment: Thanks! This explains it, and how could I forget. I was merely saying there are more "loves" other than romantic love. But yea the quote explains enough and I guess it is a squib question.

Comment: Children age. It didn't say when she would. For all they knew it could have been 20 years after they found The One that she fell for him.

Comment: @Murphy You're right, it could well have been that Trinity would fall in love with one of the potentials when they grew up - but that still gives them a decade or longer to be searching for a The One who is already an adult.

Comment: "unless Trinity was destined to fall in love with a child (a topic I'm sure that no one wants to deal with)..." Except for Stephenie Meyer.

Comment: Nowhere did it say that her loving him was tied to the discovery of his Oneness.  And prophecies tend to muck with expectations a bit.  So it's valid fulfillment if the spoon bending kid were the One, they knew he was the One, and he acted as the One for ten years before she falls in love with him.

Comment: @Murphy They were children when in The Matrix.  We don't know if they were children inside the pod.

Answer (score 1):

The children probably are not potential Ones, just potential recruits.

> **MORPHEUS**: I feel that I owe you an apology. There is a rule that we do not free a mind once it reaches a certain age.  It is dangerous. They have trouble letting go... Their mind turns against them. I've seen it happen.  I broke the rule because I had to.

It's not clear what that 'certain age' is, but if there is an age limit beyond which freeing people becomes difficult or dangerous, it would make sense to begin training potential recruits young. It would also make sense, given Zion's limited resources, to let the Matrix handle keeping them fed until their bodies are grown, and only free them in their late teens or so.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the children aren't necessarily potential "ones" but potential paragons of some power - ie the key makers or the Merovingian, the Oracle etc...